# Custom Sitecore cache by role

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, sitecore

I'm trying to figure out the best way to cache html by Sitecore roles. I'm thinking by using the VaryByParam but I don't statically bind my renderings. They are all dynamically added to the page. I'm using Web forms, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I did end up using part of your solution Jan. I'm adding an answer because it wasn't as easy as just enabling Vary By Param.

First I had to implement a RoleManager

```
public class RoleManager
{
    private User currentUser;
    public string GetReadRole(Item item)
    {
        currentUser = Sitecore.Context.User;
        //int found = 0;
        foreach (Role role in currentUser.Roles)
        {
            return role.LocalName; //return the role they are in
        }
        return "";

    }
}
```

Then I had to make a sublayout that inherits from Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Sublayout to replace the default sublayout in sitecore.

```
protected RoleManager roleManager = new RoleManager();
    public override string GetCacheKey()
    {
        Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext site = Sitecore.Context.Site;
        if ((Cacheable && ((site == null) || site.CacheHtml)) && !SkipCaching())
        {
            if (VaryByParm)
            {
                return base.GetCacheKey() + "_#userRole:" + roleManager.GetReadRole(this.GetItem());
            }

            return base.GetCacheKey();
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Now all there was left to do was add a sublayout rendering to replace the rendering the pipeline calls.This class inherited from Sitecore.Web.UI.SublayoutRenderingType

```
public override System.Web.UI.Control GetControl(NameValueCollection parameters, bool assert)
    {
        var sublayout = new RoleSublayout();
        foreach (string key in parameters.Keys)
        {
            ReflectionUtil.SetProperty(sublayout, key, parameters[key]);
        }
        return sublayout;
    }
```

All the code is now done and just need to add to the web.config
The line modified was

```
<control template="sublayout" type="Sitecore.Web.UI.SublayoutRenderingType, Sitecore.Kernel" propertyMap="Path=path" />
```

and it's now

```
<control template="sublayout" type="YOURNAMESPACE.RoleSublayoutRenderingType, DLLNAME" propertyMap="Path=path" />
```

Edit:
For this to work, you need to enable VeryByParam in sitecore

This article helped me tons
http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/sitecore_output_caching_kick_it_up_a_notch/

Answer (score 1):

The "Vary By Parm" for Sitecore html cache is for rendering parameters. Depend on your code dependencies you choose the right varBy cache parameter(s)

See:

[creating-sitecore-sublayouts-dynamically](https://www.markstiles.net/blog/2013/9/6/creating-sitecore-sublayouts-dynamically/)

[basics-of-html-caching](https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2011/10/30/basics-of-html-caching/)

Sometimes, if the default HTML cache is not to match with your logic, you can use custom Sitecore caching for heavy pieces or create your own "var By" See [Sitecore Custom Cache](http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/custom-cache/)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I read both of the provided articles and I'm still stuck. I'm using sublayouts in sitecore content editor and those link ascx files. We have a lot of users but they are broken into bigger groups, like Althelete, Hobiest, etc. These groups all see different content. I want to be able to cache output dependent on these roles but can't for the life of me figure out how to intercept the cache pipeline with the current setup I have

Comment: Can you add an code sample of your user/group logic. i think you need to add the user group as a "rendering parameters" or add it to the querystring. than you can use this a varBy cache.. otherwish the var by User probably lesser cache hits. other option Custom Sitecore Cache

Comment: Add the Custom cache solution to the Answer.